# convert scientific notation float value to a decimal variable (4gl, informix)

Tags: sql, informix, 4gl

we have an sql table with a float column storing values in scientific notation. I have a value -1.23E-256. when i run a query and assign the query results to variables i am assigning this float value to a decimal(15,2). But because of this scientific notation, values are not getting assinged to the variables in the 4gl program and throwing errors.
I tried to use convert and cast functions to change that scientific notation to decimal in the select queries but is throwing and error "value is very small to be stored into a decimal". I want to get those float variables from the database to variables in a 4gl program in decimal format. How can i achieve that?

Comment: float is a numeric datatype.  scientific notation is a display format.  Whatever is happening to you is not caused by the scientific notation.  Your error message is giving you valuable information.  Does 4gl have any functions that format numbers?

Comment: decimal(15,2) will disply 0.00

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly. You have to convert first to float and then to decimal or whatever else:

```
select convert(decimal(15,2), convert(float, '-1.23E-256'))
```

converts to: `0.00`

So, of course you loose the value, but at least it doesn't generate an error.

Answer (score 2):

decimal [ (p[ ,s] )] and numeric[ (p[ ,s] )]
Fixed precision and scale numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1.

float
- 1.79E+308 to -2.23E-308, 0 and 2.23E-308 to 1.79E+308

So it is not possable becouse the number is to small   you should leave it in float

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=scientific%20notation&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22ScientificNotation%22,%20%22scinotnum%22%7D%20-%3E%22-1.23E-256%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22ScientificNotation%22,%20%22scinotprec%22%7D%20-%3E%223%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22scientific%20notation%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D) the value

> -1.23E-256 = -1.23×10^-256

Which means you would have to shift the decimal place 256 times. You are trying to fit that TINY number into a percision of 2. Your decimal places 1 through 253 will all be 0's

Thus, @user2615302 is correct and you should keep it a float